# Non unique factorization of integer valued polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring

Is there a nice example of a polynomial with non unique factorization in the subring of 
$\mathbb Q[X,Y]$ of polynomials that defines functions $\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb Z$?

I don't think this subring is a UFD because of the possibility to multiply the unique factors in $\mathbb Q[X,Y]$ in different ways to sometimes obtain different irreducible factors in the subring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can even be done with one variable:
$$
2\cdot \left(\frac{x(x+1)}{2}\right)=\big(x\big)\cdot\big(x+1\big).
$$
If you prefer to avoid irreducibles that become units in $\mathbb{Q}$:
$$
\left(\frac{x(x+1)}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{(x+2)(x+3)}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{x(x+3)}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{2}\right).
$$

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the point of having the division by two in the factors?

Comment: Without the division by 2, the factors are no longer irreducible.

Answer (score 4):

Worth emphasis is how extremely different the lengths of irreducible factorizations can be in such nonunique factorizations in the ring of [integer-valued polynomials.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial) For example

$$ n {x\choose n}\, =\, (x-n+1){x\choose n-1}$$

The RHS is a product of two irreducibles, but the LHS can have an arbitrarily large number of irreducible factors by choosing $n$ with many prime factors.

For completeness, below is a proof of the irreducibility of $x\choose n$ from the 2016 *Monthly* paper [What You Should Know About Integer-Valued Polynomials](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.123.4.311) by Cahen and Chabert.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you!